# Adding drift to an ARIMA(0,1,1) (0,1,1) model in R

Tags: r, arima, intercept

I'm trying to add drift to my ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1) model in R, however R is giving me the error message,

> Warning message:
> In Arima(insample, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = c(0, 1, 1), include.drift = TRUE) :
> No drift term fitted as the order of difference is 2 or more.

I don't understand the intuition behind this, I've tried writing out the ARIMA model using the lag operator:

$(1-\phi_1L)(1-\Phi_1L^4)(1-L)(1-L^4)y_t=\alpha +(1+\theta_1L)(1+\Theta_1L^4)\epsilon_t$

where $\alpha$ is the drift term.

I can't see why adding a drift term to a differenced series would be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

This is to prevent fitting high-order polynomials for the time series in levels (not differenced), something that is only rarely plausible. According to the function's [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.13/topics/Arima),

> <...> if there is more than one difference taken, no constant is included regardless of the value of this argument. This is deliberate **as otherwise quadratic and higher order polynomial trends would be induced**.

{Emphasis is mine.)